# Laravel + Vue.js + vuejs-datepicker, cannot apply typeable prop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, datepicker

Hi can somebody know how to use this prop. I try to add this prop in my datepicker component but the datepicker component doesn't allow to be typeable.

```
<td class="v-dataTable__tableCell v-dataTable__tableCell--dateTime">
    <datepicker **:typeable="true"** :id="'date-from-' + row.index" 
                class="date-from" format="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                v-model='row.data.date_from' 
                v-on:selected="changeState(row.index, 'update', 'detail')"></datepicker>
</td>
```

When I try to add this prop, nothing changes.

Please help :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: I use double * to specify where I put my typeable prop. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you run npm after the changes you made in your vue.js component?

Comment: nope. I just added the prop typeable. Should I run npm command? and what command, sorry I'm beginner in vue js

Comment: Usually when I try to add prop in Laravel Vuejs, it will work after I reload

Comment: You should run `npm run dev` to compile all the changes you made, since you are working in `resources` directory, so your `public` directory has no idea that something changed, until you compile your changes with previous command

Comment: I'm using gulp to compile all the changes in frontend side (javascript). But nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my problem is. I check the package version of this vuejs-datepicker and I found out that the installed version of this package was 0.9.16

I check this version and I found out this typeable prop is not supported on that version. So I tried to upgrade my package version to 1.6.2 and It works!!!!!!! Thanks!!!

Solution: check and update your package version. **1.6.2** support this typeable prop!!!